# Why is does boost parallel graph edge takes so much more memory as compared with vertex?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph, boost-graph-parallel

```
if (world_.rank() == 0)
       std::cout << "test the memory requirements of edges only using own graph" << std::endl;
       world_.barrier(); 
//     std::cout << getpid() << std::endl;
            auto mems1 = MemoryMonitor::instance().get_all_proc_memory();
            if (world_.rank() == 0) {
                std::cout << "before create graph" << std::endl;
                std::cout << mems1 << std::endl;
            }
            size_type vertex_size = 5000;
            size_type per_batch_size = vertex_size / world_.size();

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::distributedS<ProcessGroup, boost::vecS>, boost::bidirectionalS> Graph;

        ProcessGroup pg;
        Graph g(vertex_size, pg);


        Timer t;
        for (size_type i = world_.rank() * per_batch_size; i < (world_.rank() + 1) * per_batch_size; i++) {
            for (size_type j = 0; j < vertex_size; j++) {
                Graph::vertex_descriptor from = boost::vertex(i, g);
                Graph::vertex_descriptor to = boost::vertex(j, g);
                boost::add_edge(from, to, g);
            }
        }
        synchronize(g);
        t.stop();
        t.print();

        world_.barrier();
        auto mems2 = MemoryMonitor::instance().get_all_proc_memory();
        if (world_.rank() == 0) {
            std::cout << "after create graph" << std::endl;
//          std::cout << getpid() "has" << std::endl;
            std::cout << mems2 << std::endl;
        }
        auto total_edge_size = vertex_size * vertex_size;
        auto edge_size_per_proc = total_edge_size / world_.size();
        std::cout << "edge_size_per_proc:" << edge_size_per_proc << std::endl;
        if (world_.rank() == 0) {
            for (auto i = 0; i < world_.size(); i++) {
                std::cout << "mem increase total:" << mems2[i] - mems1[i];
                std::cout << "\tper edge:"
                          << (mems2[i] - mems1[i]) * 1024 * 1024 / edge_size_per_proc
                          << std::endl;
            }
        }
```

returned below results

```
edge_size_per_proc:6250000
mem increase total:1020.52      per edge:171.215
mem increase total:1016.33      per edge:170.512
mem increase total:1029.33      per edge:172.693
mem increase total:1018.72      per edge:170.913
```

It says memory usage per edge is 170 bytes. While I test memory for vertex, it is only 4 bytes, so I wonder why it takes 170 bytes to store an edge? I have looked deeper into the source code of boost, and found that it keeps two vectors per vertex for in_edge and out_edge edges, with the definition below:

```
std::vector< boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, MyVertexDescriptor, MyEdgeDescriptor>>
```

But when I use sizeof printed its size, it is only 16 bytes, and after counting in both in and out edges, it should be 32 bytes. So where is the rest 140+ bytes gone?

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is in the profiler and the source code.

> I have looked deeper into the source code of boost, and found that it
> keeps two vectors per vertex for in_edge and out_edge edges

That only makes sense when using `boost::bidirectionalS` instead of `boost::undirectedS`.

Regardless, obviously the size of your (very very poorly named) property types (`MyVertexDescriptor` [sic] and `MyEdgeDescriptor` [sic]) is extremely important. If, e.g. the edge property is 170 bytes, then you'd expect even more memory consumed per edge.

### Diving In

Adjacency lists store iterators to out edges in the container of your choice (`vecS` selector in your example) inside each stored vertex.

I changed your sample to *actually* only use "own graph" (so removing the distributedS adaptor).

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aae48762b80d2b18)**

```
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <random>
#include <ranges>
using boost::core::demangle;

static auto const seed = std::random_device{}();
static std::mt19937_64 prng{seed};

template <typename T>static std::string detect(std::vector<T> const&) {
    return "Vector of " + std::to_string(sizeof(T));
}
template <typename T> static std::string detect(std::list<T> const&) {
    struct Hack :std::list<T>{
        constexpr size_t observe_node_size() const { return sizeof(typename Hack::_Node); }
    };
    return "List of " + std::to_string(Hack{}.observe_node_size());
}
template <typename T> static std::string detect(std::set<T> const&) {
    return "Set of " + std::to_string(sizeof(typename std::set<T>::node_type));
}

template <typename D, typename S> void foo() {
    prng.seed(seed);

    struct VProps { std::array<char, 1024> x; };
    struct EProps { std::array<char, 64>   y; };

    using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<S, boost::vecS, D, VProps, EProps>;

    Graph g;
    using VStored = std::decay_t<decltype(g.m_vertices.front())>;
    using EStored = std::decay_t<decltype(g.m_edges.front())>;

    constexpr auto vsize   = sizeof(VStored);
    constexpr auto esize   = sizeof(EStored);
    constexpr auto adjsize = sizeof(*std::declval<VStored>().m_out_edges.begin());

    static_assert(esize == sizeof(EProps) + 2 * sizeof(typename Graph::vertex_descriptor));

    std::cout << demangle(typeid(D).name()) << " V:" << vsize << " Adj:" << adjsize << " E:" << esize << "\n";
    std::cout << " - out edges:\t" << detect(VStored{}.m_out_edges) << "\n";
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<D, boost::bidirectionalS>)
        std::cout << " - in edges:\t" << detect(VStored{}.m_in_edges) << "\n";

    generate_random_graph(g, 100'000, 200'000, prng);
}

template <typename S> void foos() {
    std::cout << "\n ------ [ " << demangle(typeid(S).name()) << " ] ----\n";
    foo<boost::directedS, S>();
    foo<boost::undirectedS, S>();
    foo<boost::bidirectionalS, S>();
}

int main() {
    foos<boost::vecS>();
    foos<boost::listS>();
    foos<boost::setS>();
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
 ------ [ boost::vecS ] ----
boost::directedS V:1048 Adj:16 E:80
 - out edges:   Vector of 16
boost::undirectedS V:1048 Adj:16 E:80
 - out edges:   Vector of 16
boost::bidirectionalS V:1072 Adj:16 E:80
 - out edges:   Vector of 16
 - in edges:    Vector of 16

 ------ [ boost::listS ] ----
boost::directedS V:1048 Adj:16 E:80
 - out edges:   List of 32
boost::undirectedS V:1048 Adj:16 E:80
 - out edges:   List of 32
boost::bidirectionalS V:1072 Adj:16 E:80
 - out edges:   List of 32
 - in edges:    List of 32

 ------ [ boost::setS ] ----
boost::directedS V:1072 Adj:16 E:80
 - out edges:   Set of 8
boost::undirectedS V:1072 Adj:16 E:80
 - out edges:   Set of 8
boost::bidirectionalS V:1120 Adj:16 E:80
 - out edges:   Set of 8
 - in edges:    Set of 8
```

As you can see from the static assert

```
static_assert(esize == sizeof(EProps) + 2 * sizeof(typename Graph::vertex_descriptor));
```

the storage for edges seems pretty reasonable: just enough to store your own data and the source/target descriptors.

### Improving?

I see few ways to improve:

- avoid large properties
- optimize out edge lists for specific maximum (or average) degree by using small_vector or even static_vector
- avoid bidirectional graphs (of course, your algorithms may suffer a runtime complexity trade-off)

The last way to improve is to /not use `boost::adjacency_list` but instead model your graph concept using your own custom code. You can optimize this in any way you see fit. Of course, it is the most amount of work.

### BONUS Profiling

I forgot to include the Massif memory profiling graph of the sample program I included. Perhaps it is is of use to you:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, let me dig into it a little bit... Since I don't define any edge property, so I need to investigate why the edge takes such memory....

Comment: The property will default to type `no_property` which [sadly takes one `size_t`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e4cc2e5aef0248b). It makes [the difference between various graph models come out much clearer](https://imgur.com/Z2MbpV8) for obvious reasons. I believe [EBO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) would have been beneficial there, but no doubt there's a reason they chose this.